# What does ~ 1 mean in R function

Tags: r, survival-analysis, r-formula

Although I looked up the R docs for `survfit{survival}`, I couldn't see any information on this syntax  `~ 1` in the formula

```
survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung).
```

Could someone please help to explain what `~ 1` generally means in R?

Comment: In this case it means "fit a single curve". See `?survfit.formula`.

Comment: As a hint for how to find this - `?survfit.formula` is listed in the 'See Also' section at the bottom of the help page for `?survfit`

Comment: Thanks, @neilfws, "fit a single curve" makes sense for that _cryptic_ syntax `~ 1`.